# Fatal Error Encountered During command execution in remote Mysql connection

Tags: c#, mysql

When I connect to my remote server from C# application getting an error like

```
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): Fatal error encountered during command execution.
```

My connection string is

```
connectionString = "Server=xxx.xxx.xx.xx;" + "Database=testdb;" + "Uid=abc;" + "Pwd=abc123;SslMode=none";
connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
connection .open();
```

It is not working in some pcs.

Detailed error as follows

```
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): Fatal error encountered during command execution. 
---> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): Fatal error encountered attempting to read the resultset. 
---> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): Reading from the stream has failed. 
---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. 
---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Receive(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, SocketFlags socketFlags)
   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.TimedStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlStream.ReadFully(Stream stream, Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlStream.LoadPacket()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlStream.LoadPacket()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlStream.ReadPacket()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.GetResult(Int32& affectedRow, Int64& insertedId)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.GetResult(Int32 statementId, Int32& affectedRows, Int64& insertedId)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.NextResult(Int32 statementId, Boolean force)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader.NextResult()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader.NextResult()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReader()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.LoadServerProperties(MySqlConnection connection)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.Configure(MySqlConnection connection)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.Open()
   at Mlounge.db.DbPurchase.GetPurchaseData()
   at Mlounge.PurchaseForm.LoadPurchaseData()
   at Mlounge.PurchaseForm.PurchaseForm_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnCreateControl()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl(Boolean fIgnoreVisible)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmShowWindow(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.WmShowWindow(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
```

Comment: The error doesn't have any extra information?

Comment: https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=MySqlException+(0x80004005)%3A+Fatal+error+encountered+during+command+execution.&oq=MySqlException+(0x80004005)%3A+Fatal+error+encountered+during+command+execution.&aqs=chrome..69i57.160j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8 - any of those any help to you? Your description is really too vague for us to help you. Maybe there is something different about the PCs where it doesn't work compared to those where it does. That would be the obvious place to start investigating. Play spot the difference.

Comment: @john no other information.

Comment: @ADyson but while connecting to another remote server from the same PC it is working.

Comment: well then, there's another clue for you in your detective game. Maybe there's a problem with the route to the "non-working" server from those PCs. Although I'd have expected a connection timeout or something to be honest in that scenario, but let's work with what we've got.

Comment: Actually, can you please check if your MySqlException has the "InnerException" property populated? There may be more detail within that. There should also be a full stack trace available which might be helpful.

Comment: @ADyson Exception Text added in the question

Comment: So there you go: "A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.". There's a connectivity problem, as I suspected. Now you need to find out why. That's not really in the scope of this code or this question, it's more of a networking issue I'd imagine. Check for things like firewalls etc which might block the route. When you told john "no other information" before, that simply wasn't true. Now you know where to look for info in future :-)

Comment: you could also consider, if this is a long-running query, whether you need to increase the mysql timeout value in your client.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177197/discussion-between-shameem-and-adyson).

Comment: @ADyson. Still not solved. can you help me ?